# Location missing from New Project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2017 when I select File | New Project and then select Console App(.Net Core) I can see the text fields:

- Name
- Location
- Solution
- Solution Name

As well as tick boxes for:

- Create Directory for Solutions
- Add to Source Control

If I select Console App(.Net Framework) I only see 2 text boxes:

- Name
- Framework

and no tick box to connect to Source Control.

Why are these options missing?

Comment: Feature, not a bug.  Tools > Options > Project and Solutions > General > "Save new projects when created" checkbox.  Turned on by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I do my first Save of a project that misses out the fields from the New Project dialog, the Save dialog asks for the all the parameters.

So exactly the same, just at different ends of the process.